# "create table new_table as select * from old_table" will give the table structure as old_table to new_table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `old_table` (In oracle 10g)

I have to copy entire data of old_table into new_table.

At that moment, I will use

```
create table new_table 
as 
select * from old_table
```

Will this command create a table exactly like old_table?

For example, if old_table have some indexes on some columns.

If I use the above command, then, the new_table also have same indexes?

Answer (score 1):

It will only create table with default settings and same structure (same columns and column types) as original table. It will not create any indexes, constraints, grants, triggers and any other objects dependent on the original table.

Comment: So, How  can I create a table exactly like that? Is there any way? Please suggest.

Comment: As my predecessor writes, you can use DBMS_METADATA package to generate more detailed script. Check also GET_DEPENDENT_DDL method to get index, trigger, constraints and other dependent objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table
where 1=2;
```

It doesn't duplicate constraints (except for NOT NULL, I think).

A more advanced method if you want to duplicate the full structure is:

```
SET LONG 5000
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'MY_TABLE_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```

This will give you the full create statement text which you can modify as you wish for creating the new table.  You would have to change the names of the table and all constraints of course.

(You could also do this in older versions using EXP/IMP, but it's much easier now.)

If the table you are after is in a different schema:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'MY_TABLE_NAME', 'OTHER_SCHEMA_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```